# How can i use file upload control in dnn module programming?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, dotnetnuke

I want to use file upload control in dnn module programming.

I know there is `DnnFilePicker` in dnn, but I want a simple code that each user can upload a file and after that can display, edit and delete it.

There is this code but is not complete.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<dnn:DnnFilePicker runat="server" ShowFolders="false" ID="fpUserFiles" FileFilter="pdf,gif,jpg" />
```

In `Page_Load` event, set the folder:

```
// Limit filepath to user's folder

fpUserFiles.FilePath = FolderManager.Instance.GetUserFolder(User).FolderPath;
```

what should i do?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You don't have to use the `DnnFilePicker`. You can just use the `FileUpload` control and work with files just like on any other asp.net project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some sort of Save event on your module view, you simply get the FileId of the file that was selected by the user to save it in the database:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModelData model = new ModelData {
        FileId = fpUserFiles.FileID
    };
    // TODO: Save your model data 
}
```

In your Page_Load event, you can also load model data (if user is editing an existing model) by setting the fileID on the File Picker.  That will pre-select the file in the picker control.

```
fpUserFiles.FileID = model.FileId
```

To use the fileId in another module view, you can get it from your model data and get the attributes of the file like this example:

```
FileInfo fi = (FileInfo)FileManager.Instance.GetFile(model.FileId);
if (fi != null)
{
    pic.ImageUrl = "/" + _currentPortal.HomeDirectory + "/" + fi.RelativePath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code my problem is resolved.
each user can upload its files in its folder.
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            username = UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo().Username.ToString();

```
    }

    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var folder = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/Company/" + username);

        if (this.FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
            this.FileUpload1.SaveAs(folder + "/" + this.FileUpload1.FileName);            
        }

    }
```